# Python: nested list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a nested list issue that I cannot solve.

```
first_list = cursor.execute('SELECT id, number, code FROM test').fetchall()

second_list = cursor.execute('SELECT key FROM test2').fetchall()

second_set = set(second_list)

results = []

for id, number, code in first_list:
    name = [code]
    for a in second_set:
        if code.startswith(a[0]):
            if a[0] not in name:
                name.append(a[0])
    results.append(tuple(name))


    print (id, code, name)
```

This produces an ouput:

```
('1', '98', ['1', '2'])
('2', '12', ['1', '2', '3'])
```

I was wondering what the best way is to do a list comprehension is, so that the output would be:

```
('1', '98', '1')
('1', '98', '2')
('2', '12', '1')
('2', '12', '2')
('2', '12', '3')
```

Comment: You never include `id` in your output tuple, only in the `print` statement. Was this by design?

Comment: On an off note, you will get better performance if you select unique straight from the database. You will get back less data, while also skipping the cost of uniqueness in python. It is as simple as doing `cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT(key) FROM test2').fetchall()`

Comment: @zsquare thanks.  I guess changing it to a set is a little pointless when i can do it in the sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a nested list comprehension:

```
results = [(code, a[0])
           for id, number, code in first_list
           for a in second_set
           if code.startswith(a[0])]
```

You probably want to make the `second_set` a set of *just* the `a[0]` values:

```
second_set = {a[0] for a in second_list}
```

simplifying things a little in your list comprehension

```
results = [(code, a)
           for id, number, code in first_list
           for a in second_set if code.startswith(a)]
```

Your sample outputs seem to be based on the `print` statement, not the actual values appended to the `result` list. Your `print` statements include the `id` value too; if this is needed, just add it in:

```
results = [(id, code, a)
           for id, number, code in first_list
           for a in second_set if code.startswith(a)]
```

Comment: I don't know whether I understand it correctly . Why do we need startswith here?

Comment: Plus, this seems to produce the same output as I already have?

Comment: @AkshayHazari: the original code only includes values from `second_set` where the `code` starts with that value. You still need to do that in the list comprehension.

Comment: @user47467: this produces separate `(code, a)` tuples. Your code produced `(code, a, a, ...)` tuples.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is this included as my results list?

Comment: @user47467 Why don't you print `results` in your version and compare?

Comment: @MartijnPieters . Okay. It a substitute for the entire code. I have done it partly. 415k defeats me so bad that I've been sent to the dark ages where I can find 6 elements wood, fire, earth, metal, water and Martijn Pieters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm sorry.  I still don't quite understand where in my code this is to be inserted to? Or is this a replacement for the original code that I posted?

Comment: @user47467: the code replaces your `for` loop entirely. You probably want to replace the `second_set = set(second_list)` line with my definition for `second_set` too, read the answer carefully about that part.

Comment: @MartijnPieters gotcha.  works :) sorry for the confusion.  thankyou for your help